# Through App Script, how can I carry session data from one UrlFetch to the next?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

### Problem

I've tried several scripts including a custom function to retrieve & pass the `__RequestVerificationToken;` however, my credentials don't seem to be posting and I'm unable to validate a successful login.

I expected a successful login with the passing of the **Verification Token** but it looks like I'm unable to post credentials.

**Goal**
Write a script that auto-downloads CSV files from a logged in software and updates the respective sheets in a Google Sheets file.

Below is my most recent code. Looking for help and guidance, as I'm fairly new to **Google App Script**.

```
function login() {

  const url = "http://portal.scaleinsights.com"; // url with login form

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var html = response.getContentText();
  var token = parseWebsiteForToken(html);

  var staticToken = token;

  var username = "user";
  var password = "password";
  var rememberMe = false;

  var payload = "Input.UserName="+username+"&Input.Password="+password+"&Input.RememberMe="+rememberMe+"&__RequestVerificationToken"+token
  var options = {
    "method" : "POST",
    "payload" : payload,
  };

  var cookie = response.getAllHeaders()['Set-Cookie'];

  var payload2 = "Input.UserName_="+username+"&Input.Password_="+password+"&Input.RememberMe="+rememberMe+"&__RequestVerificationToken"+staticToken

  var header = {'Cookie' : cookie};
  var opt = {
    "headers" : header,
    "payload" : payload2
    };

  var login = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, opt);

  Logger.log(payload);
  Logger.log(payload2);
  Logger.log(token);
  Logger.log(response.getAllHeaders());
  Logger.log(login.getAllHeaders());

}

function parseWebsiteForToken(html) {

  // Find the "__RequestVerificationToken" value using regular expressions
  var tokenRegex = /<input\s+name="__RequestVerificationToken"\s+type="hidden"\s+value="([^"]+)"/i;
  var match = html.match(tokenRegex);

  if (match && match.length > 1) {
    var tokenValue = match[1];
    //Logger.log("__RequestVerificationToken Value: " + tokenValue);
    return tokenValue;
    // Store the token value in a variable or data store
    var tokenStorage = PropertiesService.getUserProperties(); // You can change this to a different type of data store if needed
    tokenStorage.setProperty('verificationToken', tokenValue);
  } else {
    Logger.log("__RequestVerificationToken not found.");
  }
}
```

Comment: What is a logged in Software?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I just meant download CSVs from the software that I'm fetching.

Comment: you're calling your other software (scaleinsights) from Apps Script ? And you get rejected by it because you can't pass the right creds, is that it ?